# Completing jQuery animations on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to perform a jQuery animation before a user navigates away from a page by clicking on a link, or clicking the back/forward buttons.

It seems like doing the animation in response to an unload event would be sure to cover all the conditions under which a user may leave a page.

However, the new page is loaded before the animation can complete. I could do a busy wait, but that isn't very elegant.

Alternatively, I could intercept clicks on anchors. But that doesn't account for back/forward clicks and possibly other conditions under which user would navigate away from a page.

Yes, I understand that this type of behavior is frowned upon because it leaves the user waiting.  However, I am attempting to do this in a very particular situation in which I believe the pros outweigh the cons.

Comment: There must be a good interaction designer in your team to prevent you from doing this :-)

Answer (score 1):

How fast a user switches web pages using his/her browser is not under your control, but only features within your page.

With the new [jQuery 1.3 live() event listener](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), you can add a listener to all anchors as you proposed, even for all new anchors created after you declare the listener:

```
$("a").live("click", function(){
  var href = $(this).attr("href");

  var animDuration = 1000;

  // Do animation here; duration = animDuration.

  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = href;
  }, animDuration);

  return false; // prevent user navigation away until animation's finished
});
```

Comment: great idea... but offcours letting the user wait is maybe not a good idea, depends on how you're using it

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not a good idea... but that's what he's asking for: to leave the user waiting before the animation completes :)

Answer (score 1):

The document's onbeforeunload event is not suitable for what the question is asking for.

In contrast to normal UI events (per @ajm's answer), returning a boolean has no effect on this event. Returning false does not block navigation, nor can it be prevented via `preventDefault`.

Browsers will execute this event handler, so whatever synchronous code is ran within there can practically delay the page from switching, however doing anything asynchronous (such as jQuery animations) is not possible and will simply be ignored (mostly) because, as soon as the function ends, the page and its JS context are stopped as the next page navigation begins.

The only return value for this event handler is a string, used by the browser to display as part of a confirmation message asking the user whether they prefer to stay or leave. (And there is no way to force their choice.)

See also [MDN documentation on window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload). (Note, there was a bug in Firefox 4.)

---

Looking at a practical goal instead - Suppose we want to show an animation between page navigations. There are several possibilities that each have a ton of dedicated StackOverflow questions and tutorials on the internet:

- Use AJAX to load content

  Whenever an internal link is clicked make the loader icon visible, start an AJAX request for the content of the other page. In the mean time still showing the old content, it's better to keep showing that with a spinner on top then to show a blank page with just a spinner. In the ajax-callback do your fancy animation on the content element (e.g. jQuery slideUp()), then swap the contents with the new content, hide the spinner, and do the next fancy animation (e.g. jQuery slideDown()).
- Hijack anchor tags and manually redirect

  Going all fancy with AJAX is nice but if you don't wanna do that you can also try a work-around for the onbeforeunload limitation: Instead of delaying onbeforeunload, make sure that event isn't triggered in the first place.
  Bind a delegated event to all anchortags on your page and preventDefault (or return false), causing the browser not to follow the link. Then do your fancy animation and in the callback do the navigation manually by setting window.location to the url from the href-attribute of the clicked anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to subscribe a listener to the Document's onbeforeunload event, which is fired when a user leaves a page.

onbeforeunload blocks page navigation until your code returns a Boolean (true to navigate, false to annoyingly block navigation), so you'd just need your animation code to ultimately raise a Boolean when it's complete.

No need to monitor links at all.

Comment: Gave it a try... I don't think that what you describe is the actual behavior of onbeforeunload, at least in Firefox and Safari.  The return value seems to be what is displayed as the message in the popup window.